# React dynamic background image using useWindowWidth

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, components

I'm having some problems on dynamic background image in react. I'm able to see the mobileImage "image-2.jpg", but the desktopImage is not loading. I've tried on applying some code as per document but my code is giving an error please have a look and help me.

Below is my code:

**ProjectItem.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import './ProjectItem.scss';
import useWindowWidth from '../../Hooks/useWindowWidth.js';

import desktopImage from '../../Assets/Images/Projects/Desktop/Image-1.jpg';
import mobileImage from '../../Assets/Images/Projects/Mobile/Image-2.jpg'

const ProjectItem = ({ desktopImage, title, viewProject }) => {

const imageUrl = useWindowWidth() >= 650 ? desktopImage : mobileImage;
const { windowWidth } = useWindowWidth();

return(
<div className="projectItem" style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${ imageUrl })`, height: '500px'}}>
       {windowWidth >= 650 &&( 
           <>
           <div className="title">{title}</div> 
           <div className="viewProject">{viewProject}</div>
           </>
       )}  
   </div>
);
}; 

export default ProjectItem
```

Below is my code:

**ProjectItem.scss**

```
.projectItem{
width: 600px;
height: 450px;
display: block;
background-size: cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center center;
}
```

Below is error:

**console**

```
./src/Components/Home/ProjectItem.js
Line 5:8:  'desktopImage' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars
printWarnings   @   webpackHotDevClient.js:138
handleWarnings  @   webpackHotDevClient.js:143
push../node_modules/react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient.js.connection.onmessage @   webpackHotDevClient.js:210
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From looking at your code I think the problem is that the `desktopImage` inside your `ProjectItem` refers to `desktopImage` destructured from the `ProjectItem`'s props instead of the `desktopImage` variable imported above your component.

So the solution is to simply not destructure `desktopImage` from `ProjectItem`'s props:

```
const ProjectItem = ({ title, viewProject }) => {
  // etc...
}
```

This also explains the warning saying that `desktopImage` is defined, but never used.

Comment: Hi Bas, I've removed destructured desktopImage from Projec tItem's props as you've mentioned and it worked thank you!